# Solution of differential equation $x'=Ax$ where $A=PJP^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix. Suppose $A=PJP^{-1}$ being $J$ the Jordan form of $A$.
>   Prove that if $x(t)=(x_1(t),\dots,x_n(t))$ is a solution for $x'=Ax$, then $x_i=\sum_{j=1}^nP_{ij}(t)e^{\lambda_jt}$ with $P_{ij}$ of complex terms.

I have a few steps....

$(1)$ Instead of a Jordan matrix we begin with a diagonal matrix. If $A=P\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)P^{-1}$, with diag being the diagonal matrix with only zeroes besides the $\lambda_k$'s, and $P=[v_1,\dots,v_n]$ being $v_i$ eigenvectors (column vectors) of $A$, which means $Av_k=\lambda_kv_k$.

Then $e^{At}=P\operatorname{diag}(e^{\lambda_1},\dots,e^{\lambda_n})P^{-1}:$ Since $P$ has inverse we know it's nonsingular, using the property $Pe^{At}P^{1}=e^{PAP^{-1}t}$ for nonsingular matrix we know that $e^{At}=Pe^{Mt}P^{-1}$ where $M$ is the diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues of $A$ as entries, so the goal here is to show that $e^{Mt}=\operatorname{diag}(e^{\lambda_1},\dots,e^{\lambda_n})$.

By definition $e^{Mt}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}M^k\displaystyle\frac{t^k}{k!}$. We know that $M=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)$ which means $M^k=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1^k,\dots,\lambda_n^k)$; $e^{Mt}=\operatorname{diag}\left(\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\lambda_1^k\displaystyle\frac{t^k}{k!},\dots,\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\lambda_n^k\displaystyle\frac{t^k}{k!}\right)=\operatorname{diag}(e^{\lambda_1t},\dots,e^{\lambda_nt})$.

$(2)$ If $A=\lambda I+B$ then $e^{At}=e^{(\lambda I+B) t}=e^{\lambda t}e^{Bt}$ because $e^{\lambda tI}=e^{\lambda t}I$.

$(3)$ Now we take the matrix $A$, its eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$ and a basis of generalized eigenvectors $v_1,\dots,v_n$. We know that taking $P=[v_1,\dots,v_n]$ then $PAP^{-1}=J$ the Jordan matrix. The last matrix is made of Jordan blocks $J_1,\dots,J_k$; then $PAP^{-1}=\operatorname{diag}(J_1,\dots,J_k)$.

Let $V_i$ be a matrix with $1's$ above the diagonal and the dimension of $J_i$. With this every Jordan block $J_i$ is given by $J_i=\lambda_i I +V_i.$

$(4)$ Applying the second part to $J_i$ gives $e^{J_i t}=e^{\lambda_i t}e^{V_i t}$.

I don't know what the next step would be. I have to stick together the Jordan blocks in order to get $e^{At}$